# Snowflake throwing random Insufficient privileges to operate on table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have daily Control-M job that randomly fails because Snowflake returns:

```sh
100183 (P0000): Execution error in store procedure SP_X:
SQL access control error:
Insufficient privileges to operate on table 'LOG'
```

The interesting thing is that it just successfully wrote to the table just a second before(inserts are the only actions against this table).  Does Snowflake throw an error when two different sessions try to insert to the same table at the same time?

Comment: Are both the sessions using the same Roles to insert into the DB ? Check if the role has Insert access to the table in that schema/DB.

Comment: `Does Snowflake throw an error when two different sessions try to insert to the same table at the same time?` No, it will have to be a lot more writers and the error would be different.

Comment: Good morning Doug, 
Need to understand the RBAC model employed and the user used to execute the tasks

Comment: I'm not the Admin, but I'm sure RBAC was configured following the Snowflake guidelines.  The role executing the failing script was executed by a role that has full access to all objects and roles across the account.

Comment: I'm still confused as to why a procedure would fail to write to a table that it has just written to in the prior snowflake.execute() call.